# What kind of information does google gether about my computer when i sign an app?

Tags: android, google-play

Google have been suspended my android market account. I will get a new one but i don't want to google relate my new account with suspended one. So my question is what kind of information does google gather about my computer when i sign and upload an app to market? Is a new key for signing all i need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Google gathers anything about your computer, at least nothing to identify that you used the same computer that a suspended user did.  However, It is possible, I think, that using your key and, for sure, your Google checkout account they can identify who you are.

That said, I would recommend resolving your problems with Google rather than create a new account.

Comment: Thanks for answer i am trying to solve out with Google for 3 weeks and they haven't responded me yet other than an automated answer. I really started to suspect that google is using bots to deal with this kind of problems instead of hiring real persons for market support team.